# How to create NA matrix in Julia?

Tags: r, julia, na, missing-data

I am successful to create this NA matrix using this R code.

```
tree=matrix(NA,nrow=(4),ncol=(4))
tree
```

**Output:-**
[image]

**Edit**:-

```
import Pkg
Pkg.add("Missings")
using Missings

Eurocall = function(S, T , K, r, sigma , N)
    
    # S : Spot Price
    # T : Time to Expire
    # K : Strike Price
    # r : Risk free rate of return
    # sigma : volatility of the asset
    # N : Length of the Binomial Tree
    
    deltaT=T/N
    u=exp(sigma*sqrt(deltaT))
    d=1/u
    p=(exp(r*deltaT)-d)/(u-d)
    
    tree = missings(Int,(N+1),(N+1))
  
    for i in 0:N
        tree[i+1,N+1]=max(0,(S*u^i*d^(N-i))-K)
    end
    
    for j in (N-1):0 
        for i in 0:j
            tree[i+1,j+1]=exp(-r*deltaT)*(p*tree[i+2,j+2]+(1-p)*tree[i+1,j+2])
        end
        
    end
    price=tree[1,1] 
    return(price)
end
```

Eurocall(10,10,11,0.05,0.1,10)

I wrote this code, but gives me this error

```
InexactError: Int64(1.2140275816016999)
```

How to  fix this?

Comment: The R solution v. Julia demonstrates just how sublimely elegant R actually is.

Comment: R is elegant and nify in a lot of ways, but this is not one of those. One could easily do `fill(missing, 4, 4)` in Julia too, without specifying what type the non-missing values are going to be - but that would leave performance on the table. Julia is designed to make use of this type information to generate very efficient compiled code, in a way R wasn't designed to. That's the reason the answers make sure to include that type info during the matrix's creation. (It makes the code more self-documenting too, since you're not going to leave the Matrix filled only with missings after all.)

Comment: @XYZ The question you've edited in about the `InexactError` is worth posting separately if you haven't solved it yet. At a glance, it looks like you want to store floating point values in `tree`, not integers. If so, change `tree = missings(Int,(N+1),(N+1))` to `tree = missings(Float64, (N+1),(N+1))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `missings` function from Missings.jl is designed for this use-case:

```
julia> using Missings

julia> missings(Int, 3, 4)
3×4 Matrix{Union{Missing, Int64}}:
 missing  missing  missing  missing
 missing  missing  missing  missing
 missing  missing  missing  missing
```

(note that it is recommended to pass a type of elements that you want to later store in this martix)

Answer (score 4):

We may use

```
Array{Union{Missing, String}}(missing, 4, 4)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using [`DataFrames`](https://dataframes.juliadata.org/stable/). It gives you row and column names and a myriad of tabular data features.

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> DataFrame(Matrix{Any}(missing, 4,4), :auto)
4×4 DataFrame
 Row │ x1       x2       x3       x4      
     │ Any      Any      Any      Any     
─────┼────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ missing  missing  missing  missing 
   2 │ missing  missing  missing  missing 
   3 │ missing  missing  missing  missing 
   4 │ missing  missing  missing  missing
```

Answer (score 0):

While the Bogumil's answer is the way to go, it is worth noting that in Julia you also have a `nothing` value (which is in some way an equivalent of `null` in other programming languages) and `undef` (which is an undefined reference).

Hence you can do:

```
julia> Matrix{Union{Nothing, Float64}}(undef,2,3)
2×3 Matrix{Union{Nothing, Float64}}:
 nothing  nothing  nothing
 nothing  nothing  nothing
```

This constructed a matrix that can hold both `nothing`s and floats. Note that there is a special type `Nothing`.

You could also do:

```
julia> Matrix{String}(undef,2,3)
2×3 Matrix{String}:
 #undef  #undef  #undef
 #undef  #undef  #undef
```

This created a matrix whose elements are unassigned references.

Finally, when creating an unallocated matrix over a primitive type, Juia will just assign some area of memory (it will not box primitive type around pointers as primitive arrays just present some area of memory for performance):

```
julia> Matrix{Float64}(undef,2,3)
2×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 7.71946e-316  7.71946e-316  7.71947e-316
 7.71946e-316  7.71947e-316  0.0
```

You can see that whatever was there in my RAM ended in the matrix.

To add to the list - in some performance critical implementations people use `NaN`s from the floating point arithmetic to represent missing values. This is almost never the way to go unless you exactly know what you are doing:

```
julia> typeof(NaN)
Float64

julia> fill(NaN, 3,4)
3×4 Matrix{Float64}:
 NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: The answers here describe the differences between these values in more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61936371/usage-and-convention-differences-between-missing-nothing-undef-and-nan-in-jul

Comment: Can anybody help me, in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73354123/how-to-write-the-julia-version-of-portfolio-optim-of-r